# Bootstrap CDN doesn´t work and have error in console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I tried to use Bootstrap 4.5 with the CDN that they have on their main page, however, after I inserted all the lines of code into my project I have a lot of issues with my custom css and the bootstrap carousel doesn't work. When I look at the inspector I see the following message:
[image]

The CDN codes that i used are the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The "link" before the other links like Google Fonts, my custom css and fontawesome, and the scripts before the final body tab, so I don´t know, THANKS!

*Sorry for my english, i don´t speak this language*

Comment: The error seems to indicate this is a problem with one of your extensions. Could you try accessing the website in private mode?

Comment: I already try to open the project in private mode but doesn´t change anything

Comment: The source map is most likely not the issue here I would guess :)

Comment: My mistake!, in the private mode the message of the console change: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at Object.jQueryDetection (util.js:176)
    at util.js:192
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6`

Comment: I dont´t have more the error in console after i try another cdn, but the problem now is that my css is like corrput, some styles work fine and another dont be apply, i don´t understan

Comment: The error message mean you need to include jquery first before bootstrap. Bootstrap is depending on jquery.

Comment: Yep, I try it but my custom css stay like corrupted :/

Answer (score 0):

Your cdn links are from an older version - 4.4.1, not - 4.5.0.
Here are the correct links:

```
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/